# How to make BasicAuthentication in SolrJ - CloudSolrClient?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am using Solr 7.5 Server and I had used External Zookeeper.When I browse using the Solr Admin UI It ask authentication to me.

For Java Client I had used the below Code

```
    BasicAuthSolrClientCache bs = new BasicAuthSolrClientCache("solr", "SolrRocks");

    CloudSolrClient solrCloudClient = bs.getCloudSolrClient(zkHost);
    solrCloudClient.setDefaultCollection("sample");

    SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
    doc.addField("cat", "book");
    doc.addField("id", "book-1");
    doc.addField("name", "The Legend of the Hobbit part 1");
    solrCloudClient.add(doc);
    solrCloudClient.commit();
    solrCloudClient.close();
```

BasicAuthSolrClientCache.java

```
 public class BasicAuthSolrClientCache extends SolrClientCache {

 private static final Logger log = 
 LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

 private final Map<String, SolrClient> solrClients = new HashMap<>();
 private final String username;
 private final String password;

 public BasicAuthSolrClientCache(String username, String password) {
 this.username = username;
 this.password = password;
}

@Override
public synchronized CloudSolrClient getCloudSolrClient(String zkHost) {
CloudSolrClient client;
if (solrClients.containsKey(zkHost)) {
  client = (CloudSolrClient) solrClients.get(zkHost);
} else {
  client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder()
      .withZkHost(zkHost)
      .withHttpClient(getHttpClient())
      .build();
  client.connect();
  solrClients.put(zkHost, client);
}

return client;
```

}

```
 @Override
 public synchronized HttpSolrClient getHttpSolrClient(String host) {
  HttpSolrClient client;
  if (solrClients.containsKey(host)) {
   client = (HttpSolrClient) solrClients.get(host);
  } else {
  client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(host)
      .withHttpClient(getHttpClient())
      .build();
   solrClients.put(host, client);
  }
 return client;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
 for(Map.Entry<String, SolrClient> entry : solrClients.entrySet()) {
  try {
    entry.getValue().close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Error closing SolrClient for " + entry.getKey(), e);
  }
}
solrClients.clear();
}

private HttpClient getHttpClient() {
 CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
 UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = new 
 UsernamePasswordCredentials(this.username, this.password);
 provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
 return 


HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider).
build();
 }
}
```

But it give the exception like the below,

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$RouteException: IOException occured when talking to server at: http://192.168.0.104:8983/solr/gettingstarted_shard2_replica1 at

How to authenticate SolrCloud using SolrJ

Answer (score 3):

I found a easy way to do this.

You add a request interceptor like this so you do not have to worry about creating a properly configured HttpClient instance yourself. This will just add the interceptor to the default HttpClient that Solrj creates.

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.addRequestInterceptor(new SolrPreemptiveAuthInterceptor());
```

The RequestInterceptor looks like this:

```
public class SolrPreemptiveAuthInterceptor implements HttpRequestInterceptor {

    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SolrPreemptiveAuthInterceptor.class); 

    @Override
    public void process(HttpRequest request, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
         AuthState authState = (AuthState) context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.TARGET_AUTH_STATE);
            // If no auth scheme available yet, try to initialize it preemptively
            if (authState.getAuthScheme() == null) {
                log.info("No AuthState: set Basic Auth");

                HttpHost targetHost = (HttpHost) context.getAttribute(HttpCoreContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
                AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(targetHost.getHostName(), targetHost.getPort());

                CredentialsProvider credsProvider = (CredentialsProvider) context.getAttribute(HttpClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER);

                Credentials creds = credsProvider.getCredentials(authScope);
                if(creds == null){
                    log.info("No Basic Auth credentials: add them");
                    creds = getCredentials(authScope);
                }
                authState.update(new BasicScheme(), creds);
            }

    }


    private Credentials getCredentials(AuthScope authScope) {

        String user = "";
        String password = "";
        UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(user, password);

        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, creds);
        log.info("Creating Basic Auth credentials for user {}", user);

        return credsProvider.getCredentials(authScope);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use UpdateRequest for indexing requests to do a basic authentication via SolrJ:

```
UpdateRequest ur = new UpdateRequest();
ur.add(doc);
ur.setBasicAuthCredentials("YOU USER NAME", "USER PASSWORD");
ur.setCommitWithin(COMMIT_WITHIN_INTERVAL);
ur.process(cloudSolrClient);
```