# Getting solr index fields list from protected solr instance by query

Tags: solr, protected

I have solr instance which is protected with username and password. How can I get solr fields list from protected solr

solr query to get all field list from protected solr instance

I have using solr query for non protected http://localhost:8080/solr/hbsbaker3/select?q=*:*&wt=csv&rows=0&facet

Comment: Add the username and password to the url in the regular URL-format for basic http auth? `http://<username>:<password>@localhost:8080/...`

Comment: okay so need to add string to static url then. there is no

Comment: I think the rest of your comment got lost - no what? How you add the string depends on how you're querying Solr - if you're using a library, the library might have a preferred way of providing authentication details.

Comment: I want to get solr clinet using zookeeper by using solrj java

Comment: OK, I'm not familiar with authentication in Zookeeper or SolrJ, but for regular http authentication against the cluster you can at least use several methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029375/how-to-make-basicauthentication-in-solrj-cloudsolrclient - however, in the ZK case you'd have to add authentication details (if your ZK is locked down) - I'd guess in the same as Solr does internally as it uses SolrJ For communcation between nodes.